# Finding moment of inertia about the x-axis of a ball

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

[image]

Im new to this subject and i do not know how to evaluate the integral. I really appreciate any solutions and explanations that can guide me

Comment: Use $y=r\cos t$, $z=r\sin t$,  $dydz=rdrdt$

Comment: Do you know how to convert an integral from Cartesian to spherical coordinate? You may refer here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TISphericalCoords.aspx